# Application focus changed after closing messagebox

Tags: wpf

In our WPF application We open one window for authentication as showdialog and set owner as Mainwindow. After authentication we open another window as showdialog and set owner as Mainwindow then close the previous window using coding. When close the second window manually, the focus changed automatically to some other applications. Any help on this is  highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Could you show the code?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid all trouble with `MessageBox` class, always show message box from dispatcher thread and set it's owner window properly.

`MessageBox` class uses Win32 api with the same name, and it **should not** be called from background threads.

In this case, simple `Dispatcher.Invoke` call will fix the issue.